# Guidance on Do While loop until NULL in PS

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Hello all back at it again with some simple questions for you pros out there that is difficult to understand for us noobs. I have a script that i have complied for my job that basically gives me all the locked terminal accounts and the option to unlock them with confirmation however am having a difficult time getting it to loop until NULL or at the very least -eq 1. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

```
######################################################################################################
# Written by CPineda
# This Script searches for all locked terminals and unlocks them accordingly 
# Last revision 04-28-2016
######################################################################################################

# Import Powershell AD Module
Import-Module activedirectory

# Search the windows terminals OU and display results
$ToSearch = "OU=ANOU,OU=ANOU,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL"
Search-ADAccount -LockedOut -SearchBase $ToSearch | Select-Object -Property Name,LockedOut,SamAccountName | Sort-Object -Property Name | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Search the windows terminals OU and display results 
$ToSearch = "OU=ANOU,OU=ANOU,DC=Domian,DC=LOCAL"
Search-ADAccount -LockedOut -SearchBase $ToSearch | Select-Object -Property Name,LockedOut,SamAccountName | Sort-Object -Property Name | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Enter the account to unlock.
Read-Host “Enter the Terminal account to unlock” | Unlock-ADAccount -Confirm -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue -WarningAction:SilentlyContinue

# Prompt user if they want to unlock an account again
$UserInput = Read-Host -Prompt "`n`nWould you like to unlock another account (Y/n)"


  if ($UserInput -eq "Y") {

Do {

# Search the windows terminals OU and display results
$ToSearch = "OU=ANOU,OU=ANOU,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL"
Search-ADAccount -LockedOut -SearchBase $ToSearch | Select-Object -Property Name,LockedOut,SamAccountName | Sort-Object -Property Name | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Search the windows terminals OU and display results 
$ToSearch = "OU=ANOU,OU=AnOU,DC=DOMAIN01,DC=LOCAL"
Search-ADAccount -LockedOut -SearchBase $ToSearch | Select-Object -Property Name,LockedOut,SamAccountName | Sort-Object -Property Name | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Enter the account to unlock.
Read-Host “Enter the Terminal account to unlock” | Unlock-ADAccount -Confirm -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue -WarningAction:SilentlyContinue}

Until ($UserInput -ge $null + "N")}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was over thinking the original question by a mile in my mind i was trying to create a loop for Null unnecessary variables. In the end the solution was made clear once i thought more on the syntax.